# Cryptography 5A002 App Store review

Tags: ios, app-store

I've developed an App that uses SSH secure protocol for communication between a the app and a TCP server.
Following the guidelines of the US BIS (Bureau of the Industry and Security) 
http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption/question1.htm

I'm pretty sure that my app may be classified as 5D002.

My question are:

1. What to do now? I understood that if my app is self classified ad 5D002 I don't need to require any document from BIS: is it correct?
2. What should I answer to the questions of the App Store wizard ?

[image]